# Strip \x00 and \x02 from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, strip

I am reading a file as binary to get the information it contains. My aim is to extract some characters starting at a specific position in the file and a variable length.
I read the file as follows:

```py
with open("raw_files/P1925aM", "rb") as binary_file:

binary_file.seek(436, 0)

some_information = binary_file.read(331)

some_information = some_information.decode('ascii').rstrip('\x00')

binary_file.close()
```

The output ist a variable (class 'bytes') which contaions something like:

"17627005  SWU1.1  \x00\x00\x00...."

So far I managed to to decode the byte variable to ASCII and strip the '\x00 by using:

```py
some_information = some_information.decode('ascii').rstrip('\x00')
```

The output is as follows: 17627005  SWU1.1  which is exactly what I want.

Now i have a variable (class 'str').
The problem I have now if the variable looks like this for example:

"17627005  SWU1.1  \x02\x00\x00...."

```py
some_information = some_information.decode('ascii').rstrip('\x02')
```

does not work. The output stays "17627005  SWU1.1  \x02\x00\x00...."

Any hints what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You tagged this as python-2.7, but you refer to `bytes` as a class in your code. `bytes` is just an alias for `str` on Python 2.7. Are you sure you're not using Python 3?

Comment: You are right. I'm using Python 3.6. It was a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match printable characters using regex:

```
import re
...
rawdata = some_information.decode('ascii')
result = re.match(r"[\x20-\x7E]+", rawdata).group()
```

Answer (score 4):

The `strip` family of functions only removes from the *ends* of the string; your `\x02` is not the final character in the string. If you want to remove any combination of `\x00` and `\x02` from the right side of the string, pass both to `rstrip`:

```
some_information = some_information.decode('ascii').rstrip('\x00\x02')
```